# Struts2 doubleselect doubleheader OGNL

Tags: java, struts2

I'm using Struts 2.3.15.1
While using `doubleselect` tag in a JSP as below

```
<s:form action="testSubmit">

<label>State and District</label>
<s:doubleselect list="#request.statDistMap.keySet()" name="statename" headerValue="#request.state" doubleName="districtid"
doubleList="#request.statDistMap[top]" doubleListKey="districtid" doubleListValue="districtname"
doubleHeaderKey="#request.districtid" doubleHeaderValue="#request.districtname"/>

<s:submit cssClass="submitButton" title="Submit" value="Submit"></s:submit>

</s:form>
```

...which has an Action class :

```
public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport implements RequestAware {

    private Map requestMap;

    public void setRequest(Map requestMap) {
        this.requestMap = requestMap;

    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        Map statDistMap = new HashMap();
        List l1 = new ArrayList();
        List l2 = new ArrayList();
        DistrictDTO d1 = new DistrictDTO();
        d1.setDistrictid(1);
        d1.setDistrictname("Indiana");
        DistrictDTO d2 = new DistrictDTO();
        d2.setDistrictid(2);
        d2.setDistrictname("Ohio");
        DistrictDTO d3 = new DistrictDTO();
        d3.setDistrictid(3);
        d3.setDistrictname("Alabama");
        DistrictDTO d4 = new DistrictDTO();
        d4.setDistrictid(4);
        d4.setDistrictname("Mississippi");
        l1.add(d1);
        l1.add(d2);
        l2.add(d3);
        l2.add(d4);
        statDistMap.put("East North Central", l1);
        statDistMap.put("East South Central", l2);
        requestMap.put("statDistMap", statDistMap);
        requestMap.put("state", "Mid-Atlantic");
        requestMap.put("districtid", 5);
        requestMap.put("districtname", "New York");

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

.... rendering the JSP, the second select doesn't  evaluate the OGNL

```
doubleHeaderKey="#request.districtid" doubleHeaderValue="#request.districtname"
```

rather `"#request.districtname"` is shown in the drop down.
Header value in first select works OK.

Any idea where am I going wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The options for second doubleselect are created in js so OGNL evaluation will NOT be done for `doubleHeaderKey` and `doubleHeaderValue`.

Comment: This is significant control, it increases your productivity as twice as possible.

Comment: Thank you guys ! I was trying to display a previously saved form values fetching from database and set the saved id and value of second select as doubleHeaderKey and doubleHeaderValue. Can it be done anyhow by modifying the doubleselect.ftl, using stack.findString(parameters.doubleHeaderKey) ? Thanks again.

Comment: @WasilZafar: Yes, you can try to modify template for doubleselect to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The doubleselect.ftl genrates a JavaScript function which populates the second select's options on the basis of selectedId of the first select(as a parameter). It also makes a call to this function for the first time as the page renders, just to select one of the options in second select

```
${parameters.id}Redirect(${redirectTo});
```

We can write and call our own function to populate the second select options and choose the selected option just for the first time e.g.

```
function initialize() {
        var selected = false;

        ${parameters.id}Temp.options[0] = new Option("${dhv?js_string}", "${dhk?js_string}");

        if ((${parameters.id}Temp.options.length > 0) && (! selected)) {
            ${parameters.id}Temp.options[0].selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Also, the dhv and dhk are doubleHeaderValue and doubleHeaderKey which could be in the form of OGNL expression, specified and evaluated in the ftl as below :

```
<#if parameters.doubleHeaderKey?? && parameters.doubleHeaderValue??>
             <#global dhv = stack.findString(parameters.doubleHeaderValue)/>
             <#global dhk = stack.findString(parameters.doubleHeaderKey)/>
</#if>
```

We can remove the code in the outer iterator which adds the doubleheaders to every option group :

```
<#if parameters.doubleHeaderKey?? && parameters.doubleHeaderValue??>
        ${parameters.id}Group[${itemCount}][${doubleItemCount}] = new Option("${doubleHeaderValue?js_string}", "${doubleHeaderKey?js_string}");
            <#assign doubleItemCount = doubleItemCount + 1/>
</#if>
```

In fact, there are multiple ways to achieve what you want based on your requirement. Hope this helps someone.